# How to test On mvc a GenericHandlerException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

Assuming I have a Generic ExceptionHandler class like this , using Spring Boot, and classic spring mvc, How should I test the controller?

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(0)
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    private HashMap<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<RestResponse<String>> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        errorMap.put(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestResponse<>(errorMap, null), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I was trying something like this.. but doesn't work..

```
@Test
 void givenAWrongInputDtothenReturnInternalServerError() throws Exception {
    String exceptionParam = "fakeID";

    mvc.perform(post("/customers/{id}", exceptionParam)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
      .andExpect(result -> assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof InternalException))
      .andExpect(result -> assertEquals("internal error", result.getResolvedException().getMessage()));
}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Based on above, it is more likely actual `post` method is not throwing exception back to controller but doing something internally within `post`  method itself with generated exception.